# System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer threw an exception

Tags: c#

I am seeing an error  at

> System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig.get_DefaultInstance()
> at System.Data.Entity.DbContext..ctor(String nameOrConnectionString)

as mentioned in image attached while launching program.

I already have Oracle client 11 and 12 ODAC installed on my machine.[enter image description here] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/suXSV.jpg)